# Why does #importing the .m file fix an Undefined symbols error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

I was making a program in objective c in Xcode when i got an error:

> **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Logger", referenced from:
>
>         objc-class-ref in main.o
>
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Then i changed

```
#import "logger.h"
```

to

```
#import "logger.m"
```

and the error disappeared. Why would importing the .m file fix it? and btw the program ran properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should only import header file . You are getting the above error when the .m file is not included in to your class . This may happens when your .m file is not in the **compiled sources**  under **build phases**. first see that whether it is in compiled sources . then try out with importing .h file .

Comment: I see, but how do I add it under build phases?

Comment: click on your project ->select build phase ->you can add your .m class in compiled sources

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the problem